# C# DataAdapter for SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sqldataadapter

I've created a method `ShowViews`, unfortunately it won't display.

It works when I do a select for my table with the following code:

```
select name 
from dbo.sysobjects 
where xtype = 'U' 
  and name <> 'dtproperties' 
order by name
```

But not when I try with views, any reason why?

```
private void ShowViews()
{
    SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(Connection.sqlConnString);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select name from dbo.sysobjects where xtype = 'V' and name <> 'dtproperties' order by name", cn);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    // Fills the list to an DataTable.
    da.Fill(dt);

    // Clears the ListBox
    this.lbxTables.Items.Clear();

    // Fills the table names to the ListBox.
    // Notifies user if there is no user table in the database yet.
    if (dt.Rows.Count == 0)
    {
       MessageBox.Show("There is no user table in the specified database.", "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
       this.lbxTables.Items.Add("< no user table in database >");
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            this.lbxTables.Items.Add(dt.Rows[i][0].ToString());
        }

        this.lbxTables.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried running the views query against the database directly to see if you get any results back?

Comment: Have you checked if connection string is valid?

Comment: Are the views on the schema [dbo]? Is their owner, a specific user and maybe the context in which the application is running, does not have permissions to view the views?

Comment: yes, my connection is good & the views in the database works but not in my listbox

Comment: When you do the direct select from the table you are using `select name from dbo.sysobjects where xtype = 'U' and name <> 'dtproperties' order by name"` but in the code you're using `where xtype = 'V'`, so check if the table has value for `xtype = 'V'`

Comment: Hmm, have you checked the permissions on the view? I've had that once and it turned out to be what was causing it.

Comment: 1. Try a similar query: SELECT Name FROM sys.views ORDER BY Name. 2. Which version of SQL Server? 3. You are certain that you have picked a DB other than Master, in your connection string?

Comment: What **version** of SQL Server?? As of version 2005, I'd recommend using the more focused catalog views - like `sys.views` - instead of the "catch-all" `sysobjects`. That way, you don't need to specify any obscure `xtype` values, either!

Comment: http://i61.tinypic.com/2nktojr.png , everything works including connection i tryed sys.view but it didnt work either.. its odd

Comment: did you try the query directly from management studio?